# Comsol how to link 2 parameters into parametric acoustic sweep study

Tags: comsol

In comsol I'm making a study with a parametric acoustic sweep.
I need to link the variation of 2 parameters.

In particular I need to link the frequency variation with the variation of wavelength divided by 4 (=c/f/4). Then I need to put that value variation into the PML of my solid.